# How to get values from conditional drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am seeking assistance again for my problem. This is just a continuation of my conditional dropdownlist.

```
<select name="dropdownmain" id="" title="">
    <option value="dropdownmain1">dropdownmain1</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain2">dropdownmain2</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain3">dropdownmain3</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain4">dropdownmain4</option>
</select>



//if selected dropdownmain1 this dropdown will display
<select name="dropdownmain1" id="" title="">
    <option value="dropdownmain1-submenu1">dropdownmain1-submenu1</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain1-submenu2">dropdownmain1-submenu2</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain1-submenu3">dropdownmain1-submenu3</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain1-submenu4">dropdownmain1-submenu4</option>
</select>

//if selected dropdownmain2 this dropdown will display
<select name="dropdownmain2" id="" title="">
    <option value="dropdownmain2-submenu1">dropdownmain2-submenu1</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain2-submenu2">dropdownmain2-submenu2</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain2-submenu3">dropdownmain2-submenu3</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain2-submenu4">dropdownmain2-submenu4</option>
</select>

//if selected dropdownmain3 this dropdown will display
<select name="dropdownmain3" id="" title="">
    <option value="dropdownmain3-submenu1">dropdownmain3-submenu1</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain3-submenu2">dropdownmain3-submenu2</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain3-submenu3">dropdownmain3-submenu3</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain3-submenu4">dropdownmain3-submenu4</option>
</select>

//if selected dropdownmain4 this dropdown will display
<select name="dropdownmain4" id="" title="">
    <option value="dropdownmain4-submenu1">dropdownmain4-submenu1</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain4-submenu2">dropdownmain4-submenu2</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain4-submenu3">dropdownmain4-submenu3</option>
    <option value="dropdownmain4-submenu4">dropdownmain4-submenu4</option>
</select>

**im using this js code**

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('select[name!="dropdownmain"]').hide();
$('select[name="' + $('select[name="dropdownmain"]').val() + '"]').show();
$('select[name="dropdownmain"]').change(function(){
    $('select[name!="dropdownmain"]').hide();
    $('select[name="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

How will I get the value of the selected dropdownlist when a button is clicked?

Comment: You can try using jQuery`s `$('select option:selected').text();`,now you can call this within a callback function for the button`s click event.

Comment: instea of select , use the appropriate selector which could map to the selected dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe (if I understood what you want):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var selected = $('select[name="dropdownmain"]').val();
    alert($('select[name="' + selected + '"]').val());
});
```

Comment: can u use `$('select[name="dropdownmain"]').val();` directly ? does it return selected value? shouldnt it be `$('select[name="dropdownmain"] option:selected').text();`

Comment: val() returns what's in the value attribute of the selected option. Of course if you want the text inside the option tag you'd probably have to do it as you suggested.. Btw, am I way off on my answer? Don't understand the downvote..

Answer (score 1):

**Give the submenus a common class name!**, and **give the main select an ID as well!**

jQuery code can be reduced to:

```
$('#dropdownmain').change(function() {
    $('.submenu').hide();
    $('.submenu[name="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/jKUBb/

Then to get the value of selected submenu item:

```
$('.submenu').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('select[name="' + $('select[name="dropdownmain"]').val() + '"]').val()`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var e = document.getElementsByName("dropdownmain")[0];
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all values from currently displayed select :

```
 $("select:visible").each(function() {
    console.log( $(this).attr('name') + " have value : " +   $(this).val() );               
  });
```

Here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/GAe7D/1/